# sleep / wait until the process is finished in the async loop process

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

i load a json data with request (with length 125664), and from that data, i do loop with `for` , of course I can not display it all at one time, because it can cause leaking memory and so on, how to use the rest time on each line in each, I have tried various ways, ranging from setTimeout, etc., but nothing has worked yet

currently my code :

```
request({
  url: config.url.productSource,
  json: true
}, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body.length);
  for(let link of body) {
    console.log(link);
    product(link); // call puppeteer headless browser (async)
    stats(link); // call puppeteer headless browser (async)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want `async` & `await`. Change your callback to an `async` function and `await` on puppeteer calls.

```
request({
  url: config.url.productSource,
  json: true
}, async (error, response, body) => {
  console.log(body.length);
  for(let link of body) {
    console.log(link);
    await product(link); // call puppeteer headless browser (async)
    await stats(link); // call puppeteer headless browser (async)
  }
});
```

assuming your product and stats functions are async already.

Comment: ah, you miss `function` after `async` , thanks for your help ^^

Comment: Edited. Use arrow function since it sets the correct context.

Comment: but it doesnt work, until i got `Allocation failed - process out of memory`

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out very well what you are trying to do, if it is parallelize the call to functions product and stats or make sure the foreach loop wait until both async calls get completed, so I am not able to go for the exact code, in either way there is a module called async in nodejs which let you play with what you want to do. It is a matter to organize your algorithm and construct the correct parallel or series calls.

Take a look here: [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/)

Comment: i'll take a look